# Durandal SPA Deploy to Azure Web Site with Optimizer in Build Deployment Command

Tags: azure, deployment, durandal, optimization

I ran the Azure Command Line tool to generate the script below, with the following command

```
C:\GameDev\DevPortal>azure site deploymentscript --aspWAP "DeveloperPortal\Devel
operPortal.csproj" -s "DeveloperPortal.sln"
```

the script:

```
@echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=node "%appdata%\npm\node_modules\kuduSync\bin\kuduSync"
)
IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=%temp%\___deployTemp%random%
  SET CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=true
)

IF DEFINED CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" rd /s /q "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  mkdir "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
)

IF NOT DEFINED MSBUILD_PATH (
  SET MSBUILD_PATH=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

echo Handling .NET Web Application deployment.




:: 1. Build to the temporary path
%MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\DeveloperPortal\DeveloperPortal.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. Durandal Node js Optimize
echo Running Durandal Optimizer
%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\DeveloperPortal\App\durandal\amd\optimizer --source %DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\App\


:: 3. KuduSync
call %KUDU_SYNC_CMD% -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error




::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

goto end

:error
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
echo Finished successfully.
```

I added step 2 in the Deployment area, which calls optimizer, I provided the source because I noticed if i didn't I would get an error in finding one of the js files after the optimize finished.

Everything runs fine, But the website on Azure does not update, none of the changes go through, I look at the log and it has the following:

```
Command: deploy.cmd
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
  DeveloperPortal -> C:\DWASFiles\Sites\socialplay\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\DeveloperPortal\bin\DeveloperPortal.dll
  Transformed Web.config using C:\DWASFiles\Sites\socialplay\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\DeveloperPortal\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
  Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
  C:\DWASFiles\Sites\socialplay\Temp\8bdcc230-a749-42d9-9b04-dfb7f84a5bf1.
Running Durandal Optimizer
Using default base configuration.
Configuring for deploy with almond (custom).
{
  "name": "durandal/amd/almond-custom",
  "inlineText": true,
  "stubModules": [
    "durandal/amd/text"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "text": "durandal/amd/text"
  },
  "baseUrl": "C:\\DWASFiles\\Sites\\socialplay\\VirtualDirectory0\\site\\repository\\DeveloperPortal\\App\\",
  "mainConfigFile": "C:\\DWASFiles\\Sites\\socialplay\\VirtualDirectory0\\site\\repository\\DeveloperPortal\\App\\main.js",
  "include": [
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/main-built",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/main",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/content/text/GamesLocalization",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/content/text/InstantiatedItemsLocalization",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/content/text/itemWizardLocalization",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/content/text/r",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/app",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/composition",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/events",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/http",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/messageBox.html",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/messageBox",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/modalDialog",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/system",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/viewEngine",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/viewLocator",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/viewModel",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/viewModelBinder",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/widget",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/plugins/router",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/durandal/transitions/entrance",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/services/dataservice",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/services/logger",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/appdetails",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/baseitems",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/classes",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/documentation",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/games",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/home",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/items",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/itemstore",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/liveexample",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/loginRegister",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/sdk",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/shell",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/tutorials",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/Instantiated/instantiated",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/ItemCreationWizard/itemCreationWizard",
    "C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/viewmodels/WorldWizard/worldWizard",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/appdetails.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/baseitems.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/classes.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/devmenu.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/documentation.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/footer.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/games.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/home.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/HomeGuest.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/items.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/itemstore.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/liveexample.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/loginRegister.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/nav.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/sdk.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/shell.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/titleBar.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/tutorials.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/Instantiated/givePlayerItem.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/Instantiated/instantiated.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/Instantiated/playerSelect.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/Instantiated/playersItems.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseitembehaviours.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseitemimage.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseItemname.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseitemproperties.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseitemquality.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseitemunity3d.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/baseitemvariations.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/classbehaviours.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/classname.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/classproperties.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/classselect.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/generateditems.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/helppage.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/ItemCreationWizard/itemCreationWizard.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/WorldWizard/worldWizard.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/WorldWizard/worldWizard_App.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/WorldWizard/worldWizard_Currency.html",
    "text!C:/DWASFiles/Sites/socialplay/VirtualDirectory0/site/repository/DeveloperPortal/App/views/WorldWizard/worldWizard_World.html"
  ],
  "exclude": [],
  "keepBuildDir": true,
  "optimize": "uglify2",
  "out": "C:\\DWASFiles\\Sites\\socialplay\\VirtualDirectory0\\site\\repository\\DeveloperPortal\\App\\main-built.js",
  "pragmas": {
    "build": true
  },
  "wrap": true,
  "insertRequire": [
    "main"
  ]
}
Deleting old output file.
 Tracing dependencies for: durandal/amd/almond-custom
 KuduSync.NET from: 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\socialplay\Temp\8bdcc230-a749-42d9-9b04-dfb7f84a5bf1' to: 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\socialplay\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'Web.config'
Finished successfully.
```

Seems to be fine, but it also looks like, KuduSync is maybe replacing the durandal generated files, and so I tried in step 2 of my deploy.cmd to reference the %DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%,

```
:: 2. Durandal Node js Optimize
```

echo Running Durandal Optimizer
%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\DeveloperPortal\App\durandal\amd\optimizer --source %DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\App\

what ends up happening here, is that main-built.js is empty, and my page doesn't load.

This is where I am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durandal 2.0 does not need the optimizer any longer, in upgrading to it, I did not this step any longer.

Answer (score 1):

An empty main-built.js indicates that something going wrong when `optimizer` runs `r.js`.
I'd try to manually run r.js using `node r.js -o app.build.js`. See more info at [Durandal.js optimizer not working (empty main-built.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686822/durandal-js-optimizer-not-working-empty-main-built-js/16701793#16701793)

Comment: As I read this, I realised I have my own r.js in another folder, I use to have refernce to my resources (a localization of sorts), so I thought that might be the problem. I renamed it and I tried running node r.js -o app.build.js, it built with no problems. I tried deploying again, and once again the main-built.js is empty