# Optimizing Durandal 1.2 Project

Tags: optimization, build, requirejs, durandal

I have a Durandal 1.2 project which is built using require.js. The directory structure looks a lot like the below. (Much more than this, just a snippet). Each directory contains an index.js file for the require module js, and an index.html for it's view. I'm wanting to minify and concatenate these files into one (as that seems to be the whole point of using require...), but I'm not having any luck with my build scripts. Are there any suggestions on how to go about this? All Durandal docs seem to only reference 2.0 now, so I'm not getting any help there. Many thanks!

[image: file structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a version of Durandal 1.2 docs at http://durandaljs.com/version/1_2_0/Documentation.zip and @JohnHunter uploaded them to github : https://github.com/johnhunter/durandal-1.2-docs

Assuming you're using a OOTB 1.2 layout running optimizer.exe in app/durandal/amd should be all that's needed.

Comment: It won't. You'd need to build a config file for r.js http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html and then run node r.js ... on your own.

Comment: Okay, I copied my code to a windows server, installed node.js, then ran the optimizer.exe from the app/durandal/amd directory. It creates a build file which looks like it gets my entire application. Then, it gets to "Tracing dependencies for: durandal/amd/almond-custom and just stops. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try following the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686822/durandal-js-optimizer-not-working-empty-main-built-js/16701793#16701793

Comment: Thanks Rainer. I realized it was creating the build file for r.js, but choking after that. So, I took that file and moved it back over to OSX, then changed some paths in that file to match OSX file system, and running r.js on that build file after that worked!